# WSO2IS cluster setup and the need of a local registry space

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When setting up a WSO2 Identity Server cluster there is a need of setting up local databases (REGISTRY_LOCAL1, REGISTRY_LOCAL2, etc) specific to each node (Node1, node2, etc) as described here https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database

My questions are:
* Which data is stored in REGISTRY_LOCAL in case of WSO2 IS?
* Is a local database for each node really necessary which would result in n+2 databases for a n-Node setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registry mounting information is stored in local database. And there can be other data as well. Since those data must be local to each node, you must have separate databases for them.

However, you don't need to maintain external databases for them. For local dbs, default H2 database is recommended even for production environments.

Comment: Interesting to know that H2 is recommended for production as local registry. I haven't seen that it the docs.

Comment: If you see clustering guide of APIM, it's there. https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0
(see step 10's note.)