# Start multiple wso2 APIM profiles in a single host

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to start multiple wso2 apimanager profiles in the same machine. How can this be done?

Particularly I have to start all components on one host except the gateway, which is on another node. I cannot understand how to use the profiling tool to match my needs.

Is it correct to start the gateway on the other node with the command -Dprofile=gateway-worker given that its not a cluster?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to start multiple wso2 apimanager profiles in the same machine. How can this be done?

You can copy the installation to different folders (e.g. the gateway), set the [Offset parameter](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset) in the carbon.xml for each copy (instance), change the ports in other other instances to mach the offset port and you can start multiple instance on a single host

> Particularly I have to start all components on one host except the gateway

Nope, you either specifying a single profile, or you will start an "all in one" node. There's no simple way saying you want all profiles except the gateway.

Having a default instance (publisher, store, tm, km, ..) with dedicated gateway you can start a default (all-in-one) instance and simply you just configure the gateway to be the dedicated instance (in api-manager.xml), not using the local one.

You can create your own [profile](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Product+Profiles#ProductProfiles-Howmulti-profilingworks) with selected modules, e.g. effectively starting all except the gateway module, though I don't see any benefit to do so. Disabling a few modules won't save you any considerable memory or subscription charges

> Is it correct to start the gateway on the other node with the command -Dprofile=gateway-worker given that its not a cluster?

The profile parameter has nothing to do with the cluster. The gateway instance may or may not be in a cluster with other gateway instances.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply @gusto2.
Will your first approach translate into having to configure multiple master-datasources.xml and having lots of CARBON_DB (for local registry only [one per profile], since gov+conf and UM_DB is shared)? which approach would you suggest for a production environment? I'm asking because I expected to have one CARBON_DB per wso2 product.
Is port offset a must even if I only start different profiles?

Comment: @Maio  in the distibuted setup you should not use the default (h2) database definition, as it needs to be shared between nodes (users, registry, ..). You may rather use a real (supported) database, such as mysql, pgsql, .. to setup the shared databases

Comment: I'm using postgres for every database that is shared. Initially I was planning to use Postgresql for CARBON_DB too but, given your approach to solution, isn't it better to leave just the local registry in an h2 DB instead of creating a CARBON_DB in Postgresql for every component? (publisher,store,traffic etc) @gusto2

Comment: @Maio indeed you may have a local registry for every instance, no issue about that. (though often there's no reason to make a separate instance for every compoent). Just note if you have a (HA) cluster, you need to share the registry db as well

Comment: So I can point publisher,store,traffic,gateway to the same CARBON_DB? The governance and config registry is already shared because in my deplyment I have a IS as KM on another host.
I have 3 hosts: 1ISasKM, 1AM (publisher,store,traffic) and 2 gateways behind load balancer(no cluster and no HA). Do I need just 4 CARBON_DB for local registry since publisher,store,traffic can share one? many thanks again and sorry for these questions but I'm new to wso2.@gusto2

Comment: @Maio carbon_db is by default used for registry and users. As soon as you have a dedicated shared database for the registry, users and api, the carbon_db is effectively not used. Then you can leave it to the local h2 database for each product (it needs to be defined), but it is not used at all

Comment: wow, that's totally misleading on the wso2 docs then. It says that registry has 3 partitions: local, config, governance and they must exist. Given that config and governance are remote and shared, it makes you create the local partition.. So it MUST exists but it's NOT used? wtf..In the docs it even says that it is used for local artifacts...see REGISTRY_LOCAL1 in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database  @gusto2

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593708/wso2is-cluster-setup-and-the-need-of-a-local-registry-space , so the "local registry" partition must be there and can be an h2 even in production. It will store mounting configuration and "other data aswell"(what does it even mean lol). So if I start store, publisher and tm in the same host, can they point to the same embedded h2 db?? the remote gateways will both have their own h2 instance (1 per machine[host]). Did I finally got it right? @gusto2

Comment: @Mai: `start store, publisher and tm in the same host` you've claimed you want to have only gateway separated, so the rest you shall ran as a single jvm instance (with a single registry). It may be a local h2, but feel free to have a separate shared db if you whish. Btw you should not share h2 between jvm instances. `It is not used` I meant it contains some configuration, but it's static, not under any load so keeping local H2 in prod is IMHO not an issue.

Comment: do you know if I have to install governance registry in order to have a remote (and shared) config and governance registry ? thank you @gusto2

Comment: @Maio  nope, it's just a shared database for registry records and optionally mount points https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Config+and+Governance+Partitions+in+Separate+Nodes#ConfigandGovernancePartitionsinSeparateNodes-RemoteRegistry